# Remove 'created_at' and 'updated_at' globally from all json renders by overriding 'serializable_hash'

Tags: json, timestamp, active-model-serializers, rails-api

I simply find rails_timestamps to be bloating all my requests and in fact in many cases, no. of chars that timestamps consume are more than that of the original content we actually need.

After a lot of debugging with breakpoints, I finally overriden `serializable_hash` instead of overriding `as_json` which does not seem to be called *recursively* when `:include =>` is used

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  # Ignore created_at and updated_at by default in JSONs 
  # and when needed add them to :include
  def serializable_hash(options={})
    options[:except] ||= []
    options[:except] << :created_at unless (options[:include] == :created_at) || (options[:include].kind_of?(Array) && (options[:include].include? :created_at))
    options[:except] << :updated_at unless (options[:include] == :updated_at) || (options[:include].kind_of?(Array) && (options[:include].include? :updated_at))

    options.delete(:include) if options[:include] == :created_at
    options.delete(:include) if options[:include] == :updated_at
    options[:include] -= [:created_at, :updated_at] if options[:include].kind_of?(Array)

    super(options)
  end

end
```

It works great so far, for all my basic to medium needs, but then I understood I need to move on and start using `active-model-serializers`, but then from docs it seems 'serializable_hash` is being used in many places *(and luckily it works without breaking so far..)*. **Am I doing it the right way?**

> Does this break my code *anywhere*? What consequences should I have to face?

---

Questions I have regarding this:

- Is there a specific need for those 'created_at' and 'updated_at' timestamps? AFAIK I haven't used them exhaustively: I use only for models like `Orders` to get when the order was placed or updated.
- Is there an easy way to turn these timestamps off by default and `:include` them **only if needed** as we do for `associated_models`? Something like

  ```
  # serializers/application_serializer.rb
  class ApplicationSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
      except: :created_at, :updated_at
      except: :id  #in case we have uid-hash for all models and we don't want to send id for all models
      except: :common_attrib_for_all_models
  end
  ```

  or something similar inside `serializable_hash` in `models/application_record.rb`?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding in serializers/application_serializer.rb

```
def filter(keys)
  keys.delete :created_at, :updated_at
  super(keys)
end
```

Comment: If I use `serializers`, I need to create `serializer` for each model, doing which will force me to explicitly state what attributes I need _(which obviously not include **created_at** and **updated_at**)_ and hence nullifying the need for global overrides to exclude fields...!

Comment: and unfortunately `filter` is also **NOT working** for me! From the results from [repo](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=filter), it looks like `filter_fields` on `json_api/deserialisation.rb`  is overridable. I tried your solution with `filter_fields` but still it didn't work... I'm using `Ruby 2.3` on `Rails 5.0.0.1` with `Active Model Serializers 0.10.3`

Comment: Again, even if successfully overriden, it doesn't serve the purpose as we explicitly mention fields we require!